# proof $\lim \inf x_n + \lim \inf y_n \le \lim \inf (x_n+y_n)$ (clarification)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

[proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2454657/if-x-n-and-y-n-are-bounded-show-that-lim-inf-x-n-y-n-leq-lim-inf)

The above link is the proof of $\lim \inf x_n + \lim \inf y_n \le \lim \inf (x_n+y_n)$ when $x_n$ and $y_n$ are bounded.

Could you tell me why $XY_n \subset X_n+Y_n$??

Also, my textbook gives me a hint that 'Find a subsequence $\{x_{n_i}+y_{n_i}\}$ that converges. Then find a subsequence $\{x_{n_{m_i}}\}$ of $\{x_{n_i}\}$ that converges. Then apply what you know about limits.'. I really have no idea how to use this hint. Please tell me if you know how to use this hint.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using Basic Analysis by Jeril Lebl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first question: For $k\geq n$, $x_{k}+y_{k}\in X_{n}+Y_{n}$ because each $x_{k}\in X_{n}=\{x_{l}: l\geq n\}$ and $y_{k}\in Y_{n}=\{y_{l}: l\geq n\}$. So we conclude that $XY_{n}\subseteq X_{n}+Y_{n}$.

For the second question: Let $\liminf(x_{n}+y_{n})=\lim_{k}(x_{n_{k}}+y_{n_{k}})$. Since $(x_{n_{k}})$ is bounded, then there is a further subsequence $(x_{n_{k_{i}}})$ of $(x_{n_{k}})$ such that $\lim_{i}x_{n_{k_{i}}}$ exists. Since $\liminf x_{n}$ is the smallest limit point of its convergent subsequences, so $\liminf x_{n}\leq\lim_{i}x_{n_{k_{i}}}$. Now the corresponding subsequence $(y_{n_{k_{i}}})$ of $(y_{n_{k}})$ need no converge, but there is a further subsequence $(y_{n_{k_{i_{l}}}})$ of $(y_{n_{k_{i}}})$ such that $\lim_{l}y_{n_{k_{i_{l}}}}$ exists. Once again we have $\liminf y_{n}\leq\lim_{l}y_{n_{k_{i_{l}}}}$. The corresponding subsequence $(x_{n_{k_{i_{l}}}}+y_{n_{k_{i_{l}}}})$ of $(x_{n_{k}}+y_{n_{k}})$ is convergent and $\lim_{l}(x_{n_{k_{i_{l}}}}+y_{n_{k_{i_{l}}}})=\lim_{k}(x_{n_{k}}+y_{n_{k}})$. But $\lim_{l}(x_{n_{k_{i_{l}}}}+y_{n_{k_{i_{l}}}})=\lim_{l}x_{n_{k_{i_{l}}}}+\lim_{l}y_{n_{k_{i_{l}}}}=\lim_{i}x_{n_{k_{i}}}+\lim_{l}y_{n_{k_{i_{l}}}}$, the result follows.

Comment: For the first question, why  $XY_n = X_n+Y_n$does not hold??

Comment: $X_{n}+Y_{n}$ may contain an element of the form $x_{n}+y_{n+1}$ which is not contained in $XY_{n}$.

Comment: Could you tell me why $y_{n_{k_i}}$ need no converge??

Comment: And if we follow the last line of the proof, isn't it concluded as $\lim \inf x_n + \lim \inf y_n = \lim \inf (x_n+y_n)$?

Comment: No, because we have $\lim_{l}...\geq\liminf y_{n}$ for example.

Comment: Of course $\lim_{i}y...$ need no converge, it is just a bounded subsequence of $(y_{n})$.

Comment: um.. but with similar reasoning with $x_n$, $\lim \inf y_n = \lim_k y_{n_k}$ ,which implies we know that $\lim_k y_{n_k}$ does exist, and it converges.

Comment: If you realize $\liminf y_{n}$ to a subsequence, it need no to be exactly the subsequence $(y_{n_{k}})$.

Comment: But I found a shorter trick here. Because $\lim_{k}(x_{n_{k}}+y_{n_{k}})$ exists, then so is $\lim_{i}(x_{n_{k_{i}}}+y_{n_{k_{i}}})$. Now $\lim_{i}x_{n_{k_{i}}}$ exists, so by limit rule $\lim_{i}y_{n_{k_{i}}}$ exists.

Comment: OK . I am still a bit confused, but thanks for explanation.